# PostgreSQL analog of SQL Server index(include columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, postgresql, database

Trying to recreate my SQL Server database on PostgreSQL. Everything is ok except I can't find how to recreate this index:

```
USE [mytablename]  
GO  
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [myindex]  
ON [dbo].[mytablename] ([col1],[col2])  
INCLUDE ([col3],[col4])  
GO
```

Will be very grateful for help.

Alexey

**Update:**

http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/1071/89013974.png here is db structure star+eav
there is only one query

```
SELECT this_.id as id0_0_,   
this_.device_id as device2_0_0_,  
this_.time_id as time3_0_0_,  
this_.gps_detail_id as gps4_0_0_   
FROM [scoutserver_data].[dbo].[DataMessage]  this_   
WHERE this_.time_id = 65536 and this_.device_id = 32768
```

Maybe it is not optimal atm. And im working on it also. Maybe something like this

```
SELECT * FROM [scoutserver_data].[dbo].[TimeDimension]   
  INNER JOIN ([scoutserver_data].[dbo].[DeviceDimension]   
  INNER JOIN  [scoutserver_data].[dbo].[DataMessage]   
ON [DeviceDimension].[device_id] =[DataMessage].[device_id])  
ON [TimeDimension].[time_id] = [DataMessage].[time_id]  
WHERE DeviceDimension.serial_id='2' AND TimeDimension.Day=15 AND TimeDimension.Year=2009
```

Any hints welcome =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytablename (co1l, col2, col3, col4)
```

`PostgreSQL` does not support clustered or covering indexes.

**Update:**

For this query, you'll need to create the suggested index indeed:

```
SELECT  this_.id as id0_0_,   
        this_.device_id as device2_0_0_,  
        this_.time_id as time3_0_0_,  
        this_.gps_detail_id as gps4_0_0_   
FROM    DataMessage this_   
WHERE   this_.time_id = 65536
        AND this_.device_id = 32768

CREATE INDEX ix_datamessage_time_device_id_detail ON datamessage (time_id, device_id, id, gps_detail_id)
```

However, your tables seem to be over-normalized to me.

You can keep year, month and day in a single `INT` field in your table. This will save you a join.

There might be the point of keeping `DataMessage` and `GpsDetails` in separate tables if either `GpsDetails` are rarely linked to the `DataMessage` (this is, `gps_details_id` is often set to `NULL`), or a GPS details record can be shared between multiple data messages.

It it's not, it will be better to move the GPS details into the data messages table.

Comment: Thanks, is there any guideline for indexin HUGE tables in PG?

Comment: An index will hamper `DML` performance and speed up sargable queries. It's hard to tell unless I see your table structure and the queries.

Comment: Well, there's always http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/indexes-multicolumn.html

Comment: I have separated timedimension table to query diffirent chunks of messages. Also this data will be used in reporting. Inserts are going to be once a day. Operational data wich is not persisted in db - is stored in hdd cache and aggregated before writes. On MSSQL im getting 17k data from 15gb datamessage table in 15ms. Trying to achive same thing on postgresql. GpsDetail is nullable because datamessage doesnot contain it every time. And MessageData is going to be huge - 50+Gb on single table.

Comment: Create the index on all four columns then, as described in the post. This is almost the same as a covering index in `SQL Server` except that the `id` and `gps_detail_id` are a part of the index key, not the index data. This only matters for `DML` and key lookup time a little. Range scan will be the same. Note, however, that `PostgreSQL` is much more slow in traversing the indexes than `SQL Server`.

Comment: thanks a lot, anyway PostgreSQL is targeted for customers with small IT budgets and lower loads. For other customers we provide Oracle and MSSQL solutions.

Comment: Partitioning over the time dimension is the usual approach to managing huge tables in Postgresql.

Comment: `CLUSTER table_name USING index_name`

Comment: @cdhowie: what makes you think this command creates a clustered index?

Comment: The fact that it clusters the table data on the index, and then marks the index as clustered?  Example: http://pastie.org/2309961

Comment: @cdhowie: it does not. It merely reorders the heap and marks the index so that you can omit the `USING index_name` part next time you do a `CLUSTER`. The heap remains a heap and its order is not maintained after you do an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to the table. With a clustered index, all table data are stored in a `B-Tree` or another structure maintaining the order.

Comment: If the table is clustered on the index, then the only difference is *how* the clustering is performed; the performance gain should be similar.  My understanding is that the PostgreSQL implementation is a compromise so that INSERT/UPDATE queries perform quicker, allowing the DBA to determine the re-cluster schedule (similar to how a DELETE does not automatically trigger a table vacuum).

Comment: The only definitions I can find are either specific to one database or are more general and only say that a clustered index causes the rows to be ordered on disk according to the index's natural order.  (See, for example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29#Clustered).)  Nothing about PostgreSQL's implementation contradicts this definition.  Storing the data in a b-tree may be one way to implement a clustered index, but it is not the only way.

Comment: @cdhowie: if you look at the question title you will easily find out where to look for the correct definition. `PostgreSQL` does not support clustered indexes: it cannot store table records in a `B-Tree` or any other order-maintaining structure; it does not preserve the order of the records after they have been "clustered"; it cannot rely on the order of records even immediately after the `CLUSTER` command had been run (you will still see a `sort` in the plan). Don't be fooled by the fact there is a command called `CLUSTER`: different databases call this completely unrelated things.

Comment: @Quassnoi, «PostgreSQL does not support clustered or covering indexes» — since 9.1 it does as it seems: http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2011/08/index-only-scans-now-theres-patch.html

Comment: @poige: The article concerns a certain flaw in `PostgreSQL`'s storage system which does not let to select data from indexes only (a table lookup or a runtime bitmap index is still required). True covering indexes (where the covered columns are only stored in the data pages), as well as clustered indexes (where the records themselves are stored in a B-Tree) are not supported.

Comment: Yes. I too found this "cluster" command to be verrrry misleading.  You'll notice when you run the "cluster" command on a table with 100k+ rows, that it'll run instantaneously. It should take a while if it were literally re-ordering.. which is not taking place.  We are on 9.1 and it does not support index covering either. Look up "postgres slow count query" in google and it'll explain.  select (*) from table will do a full table scan every time.  Insane.

Answer (score 16):

PostgreSQL 11 supports included columns. Excerpt from [Waiting for PostgreSQL 11 – Indexes with INCLUDE columns and their support in B-tree](https://www.depesz.com/2018/04/26/waiting-for-postgresql-11-indexes-with-include-columns-and-their-support-in-b-tree/):

> **This patch introduces INCLUDE clause to index definition.  This clause
>   specifies a list of columns which will be included as a non-key part in
>   the index.  The INCLUDE columns exist solely to allow more queries to
>   benefit from index-only scans.  Also, such columns don't need to have
>   appropriate operator classes.  Expressions are not supported as INCLUDE
>   columns since they cannot be used in index-only scans.**
>
> For now, only B-tree indexes support INCLUDE clause.

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytablename (col1,col2) INCLUDE (col3,col4);
```

---

**EDIT:**

> [CREATE INDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/sql-createindex.html):
>
> **[ INCLUDE ( column_name [, ...] ) ]**
>
> **The optional INCLUDE clause specifies a list of columns which will be
>   included in the index as non-key columns. A non-key column cannot be
>   used in an index scan search qualification, and it is disregarded for
>   purposes of any uniqueness or exclusion constraint enforced by the
>   index. However, an index-only scan can return the contents of non-key
>   columns without having to visit the index's table, since they are
>   available directly from the index entry.** Thus, addition of non-key
>   columns allows index-only scans to be used for queries that otherwise
>   could not use them.
>
> Columns listed in the INCLUDE clause don't need appropriate operator classes; the clause can include columns whose data types
>   don't have operator classes defined for a given access method.
>
> Expressions are not supported as included columns since they cannot be used in index-only scans.
>
> **Currently, only the B-tree index access method supports this feature.** In B-tree indexes, the values of columns listed in the
>   INCLUDE clause are included in leaf tuples which correspond to heap
>   tuples, but are not included in upper-level index entries used for
>   tree navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Support for index-only scanning has now been added to the beta version of PostgreSQL. It means that if an index contains the columns requested in a query, it likely won't need to go to the underlying data. Index-only scanning happens automatically.

Index-only scanning is the main reason for using Included Columns. I don't think postgres (beta or otherwise) supports included columns, so the desired columns will need to be added to the end of the list of columns to index, instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that index only scans that were added in 9.2 still require a lookup in the data if the page has been modified since the last VACUUM.

Comment: PostgreSQL 11 will support [include columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50090172/5070879)