# Select different column in PostgreSQL, different MultiColumn indexes were applied. How to make it choose the expected index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a total of over 6,000,000 rows of data in this table, after filtering it by where condition, there are about 120,000 rows of data.

##### Currently I have created two multi-column indexers

```
CREATE INDEX "IDX_module_method_height" ON "events" ("module", "method", "block_height")

CREATE INDEX "IDX_module_method" ON "events" ("module", "method")
```

When I run the following sql and it was really fast

**The fast one:**

```
explain analyze Select block_height from events where (module='amm' and method in ('Traded', 'LiquidityAdded')) order by block_height desc limit 500 offset 200;


"Limit  (cost=2748.32..2749.57 rows=500 width=4) (actual time=51.207..51.288 rows=500 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=2747.82..2757.85 rows=4010 width=4) (actual time=51.183..51.236 rows=700 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: block_height DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 81kB"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using ""IDX_module_method_height"" on events  (cost=0.56..2538.28 rows=4010 width=4) (actual time=0.061..35.880 rows=128860 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((method = ANY ('{Traded,LiquidityAdded}'::text[])) AND (module = 'amm'::text))"
"              Heap Fetches: 17403"
"Planning Time: 0.212 ms"
"Execution Time: 51.344 ms"
```

##### But when I add one more selected column (eg: `data`), it is really slow, but i really need data column.

**The slow one** (just add one more *data* field in select)

```
explain analyze Select block_height, data from events where (module='amm' and method in ('Traded', 'LiquidityAdded')) order by block_height desc limit 500 offset 200;

"Limit  (cost=14459.53..14460.78 rows=500 width=133) (actual time=12061.968..12062.068 rows=500 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=14459.03..14469.06 rows=4011 width=133) (actual time=12061.935..12062.012 rows=700 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: block_height DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 371kB"
"        ->  Index Scan using "IDX_module_method" on events  (cost=0.43..14249.43 rows=4011 width=133) (actual time=1.302..12014.625 rows=128860 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (((module)::text = 'amm'::text) AND ((method)::text = ANY ('{Traded,LiquidityAdded}'::text[])))"
"Planning Time: 0.144 ms"
"Execution Time: 12063.364 ms"
```

Why do select columns affect the selection of indexes, I need `data` fields and how should I create indexes to make sql efficient?

Comment: Add the data column to the index.  As an aside, one of your index definitions seems to be wrong, I suspect the columns are not in the same order as you described.

Comment: You should add the `data` column as an INCLUDE column to your index, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50090172/14973743

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I'm a pg noob and this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for sharing the link, it's very useful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reason is that it needs to do table lookup. your `WHERE` clause can be solved by both indices, the smaller is faster. with single field it could do `INDEX ONLY SCAN`, now it does `INDEX SCAN`.

1. you can try to make your index fit "better"

```sql
CREATE INDEX "IDX_module_method_height_desc" ON "events" ("module", "method", "block_height" DESC)
```

2. if your table have primary key, you could make your table lookup small with index only scan and LIMIT first.

```sql
SELECT block_height, data
FROM events
JOIN (
  SELECT id
  FROM events
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY block_height DESC
  LIMIT 500 OFFSET 200) x USING (id)
```

3. otherwise as others suggested you can extend your index with "include" if you use Postgres 11 or newer

```sql
CREATE INDEX "IDX_module_method_height_desc" ON "events" ("module", "method", "block_height" DESC) INCLUDE ("data")
```

Comment: Option 3 worked, that's exactly the answer I was looking for, it helped me, thanks!